# UITableViewCell: Adding constraints programmatically from a UITextView to Content View?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I'm facing an issue when trying to programmatically add constraints to the `UITableViewCell's` contentView.

In `cellForRowAt`, I'm programmatically creating a `UITextView`, then trying to apply constraints and add it to the cell's contentView.

However, Im getting the crash and error:

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x1700951d0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x12de3e150.leading == UITextView:0x12e891400.leading + 8   (inactive)>
    When added to a view, the constraint's items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled.
```

My following code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    // Dequeue the cell to load data
    let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.section == 1
    {            
        let textView: UITextView = UITextView()

        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
        textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        cell.addSubview(textView)

        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8.0)

        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -8.0)

        cell.contentView.addConstraint(leadingConstraint)
        cell.contentView.addConstraint(trailingConstraint)

        let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.contentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: textView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        cell.contentView.addConstraint(topConstraint)
        cell.contentView.addConstraint(bottomConstraint)
    }

    return cell
}
```

I do see a lot of questions regarding the mentioned error, but have not found one regarding this error when applied to a `UITableViewCell`.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let add textView to **cell.contentView** (NOT **cell**). So let change to `cell.contentView.addSubview(textView)` and it's working!